# inserting into one field value with different conditions using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table `visits`

with columns like the below

```
visit_id
member_id
logout_datetime(format like this ...'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
visit_message (like accept, refuse)
```

i want to insert the `logoutdatetime` value into visits table

where `member_id = 1` and  `visit_message  = "accept"`

how can i do that using mysql

would any one pls help on this ...

many thanks in advance..

Comment: You needs a UPDATE query not INSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
UPDATE visits
SET logout_datetime = NOW()
WHERE member_id = 1 AND visit_message = "accept"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`, since the row already exists where `member_id = 1` and `visit_message = 'accept'`:

```
UPDATE visits SET logout_datetime = '2011-10-24 07:01:22' WHERE member_id = 1 AND visit_message = 'accept';
```

If you intend to use the current timestamp for logout_datetime, substitute the function `NOW()` for the literal date in my example.